# How to set the default browser home page (IE) with C#?

Tags: c#, browser

How can I programmatically change my browser's default home page with C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set it in this registry setting:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Start Page
```

Answer (score 1):

See this, which is not in C#, but you should be able to work out the registry stuff in C# pretty easily.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/nov04/hey1108.mspx

Please don't arrange for this code to run on my machine!

Answer (score 0):

I'd hit the registry:

**For User Based Changes**

HKCU\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet

Check the keys below this key for the list of browsers on the system. Set the reg_sz value to the name of the key of the browser that you want to set as default.

**For Machine-Wide Changes**

Check HKLM\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet for the system

**Help with C# Registry Modifications**

see here:
http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive392.html

Comment: Sorry to say "bent out of shape". I see you deleted [your meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/someone-targeting-old-answer-for-downvotes-not-leaving-comments) before I had a chance to fix my wording. Nothing personal.