# Change the homepage of the browser using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, browser

Whenever the user start using my application it should check the current default homepage of the default browser if( homepage != xyz.com ) i want to change homepage to xyz.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the default browser home page (IE) with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332486/how-to-set-the-default-browser-home-page-ie-with-c)

Comment: That one is for C# and only for IE. But still I think it would be good to improve the question.

Comment: @daemon_x: Well, it's language-agnostic but I guess not platform-agnostic.  I was a bit hasty with the vote and can't undo it :(  Still, the OP can do a little research first, this question is still very close-able for other reasons.

Comment: @David - totally agree; even more I don't like the `I want` something questions.

Comment: -1 - No effort made to look for this before posting or construct a meaningful question (no background given as to why you would want this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser home page for Internet Explorer is controlled by the registry key

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

To set this from VB use the following

```
Imports Microoft.Win32
...

Module Util
    Sub SetHomePage(Dim theUrl As String)
        Registry.SetValue("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", "Start Page", theUrl)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: in my system i set Mozilla Firefox as default

Comment: how to set it for firefox browser

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note, all other browsers generally get their settings from what IE has.  For example, using VB to set a proxy server for IE will automatically do that for any of the other common browsers on the system.  Also, it is assumed that you are writing software for others and not just your personal use, I don't mean that in a bad way, just that happens to be the most common goal, and therefore want to make sure that any changes that are made are compatible with the most common cross section of users.

Answer (score 1):

for firefox you might be looking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963271/how-to-change-home-page-in-internet-explorer-using-c?lq=1). (See **nunespascal** response)

Editing the below content:

```
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.google.com/");
```

in `prefs.js` should work.